# iOS: Delete all view controllers on stack except active one

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In one view controller the user is able to restore the coredata database. After this restore a lot of stuff probably doesn't work anymore in the other view controllers already in memory even though I've rebuilt the stack. So I just want to get rid all of them, so that always the viewDidLoad methods gets triggered again if reopening again one of these view controllers.
How can I force that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should put the load data code of each view controller in another function than viewDidLoad, for example `reloadData`. All of your view controllers then also need to be subscribed to a notification (e.g. `reloadAllViewControllers`). Then using `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadAllViewControllers"` you can call all `reloadData` functions to reload all your viewControllers.